Is there a way to determine if the representation of a pointer is 'linear' in C?
In C, there is no guarantee that the behavior of pointer arithmetic reflects the behavior of integer arithmetic if the pointer is converted to an integer, as far as I know. In other words, there is no guarantee that any of the below assertions will hold:
char a[2]; // So that p + 1 is a valid memory location
char *p = a;
assert(p + 1 == (char *)((uintptr_t)p + 1));

int x;
int *p = &x;
assert((intptr_t)p % sizeof(int) == 0);

On most systems these will hold. The trailing bits of the integer representation of a pointer will represent the pointer alignment, and that adding a certain offset to a pointer is the same as adding the offset times the size of the pointer type to the integer representation of the pointer.
However, is there any way to determine, ideally at compile time, whether on any particular implementation, those assumptions will always hold true for any pointer, provided the pointer arithmetic would have produced a valid pointer anyway, since the Standard does not guarantee them? For example, to fail early on unsupported implementations, fallback on an alternative implementation, etc.

I think that the first assertion holds.  I think that for as long as p points within a[], you can do pointer arithmetic, and it will reflect integer arithmetic. You can subtract two pointers if you have to, and the size_t result will be the number of elements apart they are, if they were pointing into the same array.

@MikeNakis Subtracting 2 pointers will produce an integer, but they are still pointers when subtracting them. I am not sure of a guarantee that casting them to integers first and then subtracting them would yield the number of bytes, i.e., the number of elements times the size of each element, separating them.

okay that, I do not know. I know for sure that it would work on x86, but it might be in UB territory.

(p - q) * sizeof *p will give the number of bytes (p, q pointing to the same object).

@WeatherVane Yes, but I believe abs((uintptr_t)p - (uintptr_t)q) is not guaranteed to give the same result, correct?

What sort of answer are you looking for here? As stated, the answer is no. The C standard does not provide any way to do this, and therefore there is no way to always make determination. Do you just want confirmation of that? A particular C implementation could provide this information, via a predefined preprocessor macro or other means. Are you seeking information on that? You are already on the wrong track saying “On most systems these will hold” because these properties are formally features of C implementations, not of the systems they target.

Re “any way to determine… provided the pointer arithmetic would have produced a valid pointer anyway”: This is ill posed. Suppose in some C implementation the integers corresponding to pointers (that is, the integers resulting from converting the pointers to uintptr_t) for consecutive pointers (say to the consecutive elements of an array of char) are not consecutive. Then (uintptr_t) p + 1 may not correspond to any pointer into the array, and hence (char *) ((uintptr_t) p + 1) does not satisfy “would have produced a valid pointer anyway”,…

… so you are asking whether the test would hold for an invalid pointer supposing a valid pointer would have been produced. In other words, you are asking if x is equal to y, assuming that y is valid, given that y is invalid. It does not make sense as a question.

@EricPostpischil What I meant is assuming p + 1 is a valid pointer, not assuming (char *)((uintptr_t)p + 1) is a valid pointer. I am ruling out cases where p + 1 is out of bounds or something, so would be invalid even if (char *)((uintptr_t)p + 1) would have been valid.

@CPlus: As I wrote, the C standard does not provide any way to do this. I did not write that the standard does not guarantee linear pointers. Yes, there are some things that the standard does not guarantee (such as whether int uses two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude) but that you can test in a guaranteed way using things fully specified by the standard. Linear pointers are not one of them: I can assure you from my knowledge of the standard that the standard does not provide any means by which you can reliably test this.

@EricPostpischil Then the answer to this question is, 'You can't.'

assert((intptr_t)p % sizeof(int) == 0); could fail even intptr_t is a linear address. You probably meant assert((intptr_t)p % _Alignof(int) == 0);.

@IanAbbott Good point.

Per discussion in comments, the question is whether the specifications of the C standard provide a reliable way to determine whether the assertions will hold true in any particular C implementation.  (So the question is not whether a C implementation might provide some way to know this, as by predefining a preprocessor macro that a program could test. The question is whether there is a test that works in all C implementations.)
The answer is no.
Since this answer relies on the fact there is nothing for this in the C standard, there is no way to demonstrate it other than referring to the whole of the C standard. I am fairly familiar with the current C standard and believe it does not provide any such mechanism.
Note 69 to C 2018 6.3.2.2 5 tells us “The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment,” but this is not a normative part of the standard, and I believe there is nothing in the standard which says that any information about this mapping should be provided by a C implementation. Nor are there any stated properties of pointers and mappings to integers that would provide tests of whether the assertions always hold.

You can't really do pointer arithmetic in an integer constant expression. So the only way to properly compile-test this I believe is create another program and output a preprocessor constant on which you can do #if.
However, that might not be necessary. A de-facto compiletime expression might do. On both gcc and clang a test such as:
char a[2];
if (a + 1 != (char *)((uintptr_t)a + 1)) abort();

is optimized out (not on clang with the char *p = a; assignment), i.e., the test if treated as a de-facto compiletime constant (https://godbolt.org/z/z85a9W3E8). Relying on this optimization might be enough for you.
To test for any pointer, you should test pointers types allowed to have different representations. Native pointers types may. struct/union pointers may not.
Or maybe don't test and declare platforms where it doesn't hold as not worth supporting.

But does a + 1 == (char *)((uintptr_t)a + 1) guarantee a + 2 == (char *)((uintptr_t)a + 2).

@CPlus Optimizes out just the same (https://godbolt.org/z/xEEKsWKdn). You can try for a bunch of combos, but honestly I think you're being overly paranoid. I'd just assume a reasonable pointers-are-integers implementation-defined behavior for uintptr_t<=>pointer mappings and arithmetic and not even try to support exotic platforms.

@CPlus - The standard doesn't guarantee that there even is a type uintptr_t wide enough to hold a char*. So there is no way to make this 100% portable.

@BoP But whether there is is easily testable. If uintptr_t is not defined, there will be a compile-time error.

@CPlus You can also #if test for the existence of UINTPTR_MAX in stdint.h.
